# Printing unexpected blank lines and crash

Tags: c++, c++11, crash

For a school project I need to make a constructor with a recursive sort function that is given from a teacher in it, with a few function that I had to make myself. When I start the program the result shows a few blank lines and then the expected output. But when I increase int_buffer a(100) or higher and trys again the program just crashes. I think it might be memory leak, but not quite sure and don't know how to fix the problem either. I think that the problem is in int_sorted.cpp

**Code:
main.cpp:**

```
#include "int_buf.h"
#include "int_sorted.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(int_buffer& buf){
    for (int* i = buf.begin();i != buf.end();i++) {

    }
    for (const int* i = buf.begin(); i != buf.end(); i++) {

    }
}

int main(){
    int_buffer a(100);
    int_buffer b(50);
    int r[] = {1,4,10,2,54,3,6,20};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        a[i] = std:: rand();
        b[i] = std::rand();
    }
    int_sorted x(a.begin(), a.size());

    }
    std::cout << "\n";*/



    for (int i = 0; i < x.size();i++) {
        std::cout<<*(x.begin() + i)<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**int_buf.h:**

```
#ifndef INT_BUF_H
#define INT_BUF_H
#include <cstdlib>

class int_buffer {
public:
    bool check_sorted(int_buffer int_check);
    explicit int_buffer(size_t size);
    int_buffer(const int * source, size_t size);
    int_buffer(const int_buffer & rhs);
    int_buffer(int_buffer && rhs);
    int_buffer & operator =(const int_buffer & rhs);
    int_buffer & operator =(int_buffer && rhs);
    int& int_buffer::operator[](size_t index);

    size_t size() const;
    int * begin();
    int * end();

    const int* begin() const;
    const int* end() const;
    ~int_buffer();
private:
    size_t sz;
    int* buf;

};

#endif
```

**int_buf.cpp:**

```
#include "int_buf.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

bool int_buffer::check_sorted(int_buffer int_check){
    int* a = int_check.begin();
    int* b = nullptr;
    while (a != int_check.end() -1){
        b= a + 1;
        if (*a > *b){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            a = b;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(size_t size) :sz(size), buf(new int[size]){}

int_buffer::int_buffer(const int* source, size_t size) : sz(size), buf(new int[size]){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz;i++){
        buf[i] = *(source+i);
    }
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(const int_buffer& rhs):sz(rhs.sz),buf(new int[rhs.sz]){
    std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
}

int_buffer::~int_buffer(){
    delete[] buf;
}

int_buffer::int_buffer(int_buffer && rhs) :buf(nullptr), sz(0){
    std::swap(buf, rhs.buf);
    std::swap(sz, rhs.sz);
}

int_buffer& int_buffer::operator =(const int_buffer & rhs){
    int_buffer temp(rhs);
    std::swap(temp.buf,buf);
    std::swap(temp.sz,sz);
    return *this;
}

int_buffer & int_buffer::operator =(int_buffer&& rhs){
    std::swap(buf, rhs.buf);
    std::swap(sz, rhs.sz);

    return *this;
}

int& int_buffer::operator[](size_t index){
    return buf[index];
}

size_t int_buffer::size() const{
    return sz;
}

int* int_buffer::begin(){
    return buf;
}

int* int_buffer::end(){
    return buf + sz;
}

const int* int_buffer::begin() const{
    return buf;
}

const int* int_buffer::end() const{
    return buf + sz;
}
```

**int_sorted.h:**

```
#ifndef INT_SORTED_H
#define INT_SORTED_H
#include "int_buf.h"

#include <iostream>

class int_sorted{
public:
    int_sorted(const int* source, std::size_t size);
    std::size_t size() const;
    int* insert(int value);
    const int* begin() const;
    const int* end() const;
    int_sorted merge(const int_sorted& merge_with) const;
    int_sorted sort(const int*begin, const int* end);
    void int_sorted::selSort(int_sorted& arr, int size);
private:
    int_buffer buffer;
};


#endif
```

**int_sorted.cpp:**

```
#include "int_sorted.h"
#include "int_buf.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

int_sorted::int_sorted(const int* source, size_t size) :buffer(source, size){
    if (buffer.size() < 1) {}
    else {
        if (buffer.check_sorted(buffer)) {}
        else {
            int_buffer tmp(buffer.begin(), 0);
            tmp = sort(buffer.begin(), buffer.end()).buffer;
            buffer = tmp;
        }
    }
}

size_t int_sorted::size() const{
    return buffer.size();
}

int* int_sorted::insert(int value) {

    int_buffer tmp(buffer.size()+1);

    for (int i =0; i < buffer.size();i++) {
        tmp[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    tmp[buffer.size()] = value;
    this->buffer = tmp;
    return (buffer.end()-1);
}

    const int* int_sorted::begin() const{
    return buffer.begin();
}

    const int* int_sorted::end() const{
    return buffer.end();
}



    int_sorted int_sorted::merge(const int_sorted& merge_with) const{
        int_sorted c(this->begin(), 0);
        const int* travA = this->begin();
        const int* travB = merge_with.begin();

        int tCountA = 0;
        int tCountB = 0;

        while ((travA + tCountA)!=this->end()&&(travB + tCountB )!=merge_with.end()){
            if (travA[tCountA] < travB[tCountB]){
                c.insert(travA[tCountA]);

                tCountA++;
            }
            else{
                c.insert(travB[tCountB]);

                tCountB++;
            }
        }
        while ((travA + tCountA)!=this->end()){
            c.insert(travA[tCountA]);

            tCountA++;
        }
        while ((travB + tCountB) != merge_with.end()){
            c.insert(travB[tCountB]);

            tCountB++;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        return c;
}


    int_sorted int_sorted::sort(const int* begin, const int* end) {
            if (begin == end)return int_sorted(begin, 1);
            if (begin == end - 1)return int_sorted(begin, 1);
            ptrdiff_t half = (end - begin) / 2;
            const int* mid = begin + half;
            return sort(begin, mid).merge(sort(mid, end));
    }
```

This is what it looks like when I have int_buffer a(20);

[unexpected blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQRQG.jpg)

Comment: So you wrote all of this code and unit tested all of these functions?  What about the usage of the debugger?  And why not simply use `std::vector<int>`?  Also if this is a school exercise, why not at least `std::sort` to see if your iterators are working correctly?

Comment: When I use the the debugger the blank lines often appear after a run through of the sort function in int_sorted. But I pretty new to the debugger so I'am not sure how to use it yet. It was required in the instruction that I have to create these classes and then sort them. I tested every function by itself and it work like how I wanted. But when I applied it to the int_sorted constructor the blank lines appear and if I increase int_buffer a(100) or something higher the program just crash.

Comment: Off the top, since `a` is longer than `b`, `b[i] = std::rand();` exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun once `i` exceeds `b.size()`

Comment: `int_sorted::merge` prints blank lines, for reasons unclear. This is probably what you observe.